# Hosting on amazon s3 for private group

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, authentication, amazon-s3, web

I was researching on hosting a static website on Amazon S3, but needs to make it accessible only for certain group of people who knows credentials.

Couldn't find any option other than IP restrcition below. I can't do this as I don't know IP for every person who would access this.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testfoo/*",
        "Condition": {
          "IpAddress": {
            "aws:SourceIp": "150.101.204.0/24"
          },
          "NotIpAddress": {
            "aws:SourceIp": "150.101.204.188/32"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

I am looking for an option like we do it in apache with a .htaccess where basic auth username and password will be requested before granting access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm editing this answer to expand the answer on how to implement a basic auth for your static website hosted on an S3 bucket using cloudfront and lambda@edge. I used this [article](https://hackernoon.com/serverless-password-protecting-a-static-website-in-an-aws-s3-bucket-bfaaa01b8666) for reference on using the lambda@Edge as a way to implement serverless basic auth for your s3 bucket.

> In a nutshell, Lambda@Edge allows you to attach AWS Lambda functions to CloudFront behaviors. CloudFront is Amazon’s CDN solution and can sit in-front of a S3 bucket, providing low latency responses, high transfer speeds, support for custom domains with free SSL certificates from Amazon and it integrates with other AWS services, now including Lambda.

---

### S3 Bucket Setup

I won't go in the details on how to create an S3 bucket, but basically after you create an S3 bucket (e.g. s3-bucket-secure-example), upload your files and enabling static website hosting in the properties. No need to enable any permissions at this point.And if you try to access your s3 bucket using the URL, you should get access denied.

---

### Setting up the Cloudfront

note:this is minimum basic setup to use the cloudfront for your s3 bucket

Referencing this [walkthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-cloudfront-walkthrough.html), create a cloudfront distribution from [here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/home?#).

1. Create Distribution
2. Click on Get started for web
3. Under Origin Domain Name, put your S3 bucket static website endpoint.
4. Under Origin Settings, select "Yes" for Restrict Bucket Access. This will prevent users bypassing the cloudfront distribution and going directly to the S3 bucket url. You can then create a new identity under 'Origin Access Identity', or use an exisiting one, and let it update bucket policy to grant read permissions for this cloudfront distribution, or you can manually update them.
   [image]
5. You can leave the remaining settings for 'Default Cache Behavior Settings' as default for now, or adjust them based on what you want.
6. Under Distribution settings, you can select the price class you want, and under Default Root Object, you can put the object you want to return from your bucket (e.g. index.html).
7. Create distribution. It will take a while for this process to complete. You can go the Cloudfront Distributions home and go to the domain name it gave you (e.g. d3xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net) to see your s3 bucket static website.

---

### Setting up a [lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-how-it-works.html) function

Note: This trigger (cloudfront) used by this function is only available for US East (N. Virginia) Region (us-east-1) at the moment of writing.

1. In your aws console home, go to Lambda under Compute.
2. Click on create a function.
3. Fill in the details: Name your function any name you want, and select 'Create new role from template'. For role name, you can put any name as well, and you can select basic edge lambda permissions.
   [image]
4. Click on create function.
5. Inside the function, and under the Function Code section, add your authentication code (the referenced [article](https://hackernoon.com/serverless-password-protecting-a-static-website-in-an-aws-s3-bucket-bfaaa01b8666) above has a sample function to use). Then click on Save. Then under actions, publish a new version. Give it a description and click on publish.
6. Copy the ARN from the top corner and go back to your cloudfront distribution. Click on the id, then go to the behaviours tab. Select your behaviour and click on edit. Then at the bottom of the page you will find Lambda function associations.
7. Select "Viewer request" for event type, and paste in your lambda function ARN. 
   [image]
   Then click, "Yes, Edit". Give it some time to update.

   You can also check the cloudfront distribution has been associated with your function by going back to the function and see its associated now.
   [image]

Comment: While these links both provide good and valuable information, answers on Stack Overflow need to provide *answers* -- not just (or not primarily) links to off-site resources.  Please consider expanding the answer to at least give an overview and preferrably some detail of what those posts are recommending, particularly the first one, since it actually provides a solution to the exact issue at hand.  At the same time, be certain that you are clear which words are yours and which are from others, using blockquotes and clear attribution.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is not a web server. It cannot process the contents of a page.

To selectively control access, you would need some form compute logic that can determine whether access should be permitted. This is not available as part of S3.

The closest equivalent would be using [Amazon CloudFront cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Cookies.html) to grant access, but you would still need a way of initially serving the cookies.

A more capable solution could be created that calls API Gateway and Lambda but that's getting a bit too complex for a simple static website.

Answer (score 0):

By now, this has become relatively straightforward on AWS. It's basically 3 things that need to be done:

1. Create a CloudFront function to add Basic Auth into the request.
2. Configure the Origin of the CloudFront distribution correctly in a few places.
3. Activate the CloudFront function.
   That's it, no particular bells & whistles otherwise. Here's what I've done:

First, go to CloudFront, then click on Functions on the left, create a new function with a name of your choice (no region etc. necessary) and then add the following as the code of the function:

```
function handler(event) {

    var user = "myuser";
    var pass = "mypassword";

    function encodeToBase64(str) {
        var chars =
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
        for (
            // initialize result and counter
            var block, charCode, idx = 0, map = chars, output = "";
            // if the next str index does not exist:
            //   change the mapping table to "="
            //   check if d has no fractional digits
            str.charAt(idx | 0) || ((map = "="), idx % 1);
            // "8 - idx % 1 * 8" generates the sequence 2, 4, 6, 8
            output += map.charAt(63 & (block >> (8 - (idx % 1) * 8)))
        ) {
        charCode = str.charCodeAt((idx += 3 / 4));
        if (charCode > 0xff) {
            throw new InvalidCharacterError("'btoa' failed: The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range."
        );
        }
        block = (block << 8) | charCode;
      }
      return output;
    }


    var requiredBasicAuth = "Basic " + encodeToBase64(`${user}:${pass}`);
    var match = false;
    if (event.request.headers.authorization) {
        if (event.request.headers.authorization.value === requiredBasicAuth) {
            match = true;
        }
    }

    if (!match) {
      return {
        statusCode: 401,
        statusDescription: "Unauthorized",
        headers: {
          "www-authenticate": { value: "Basic" },
        },
      };
    } 

    return event.request;
}
```

Then you can test with directly on the UI and assuming it works and assuming you have customized username and password, publish the function.

Please note that I have found individual pieces of the function above on the Internet so this is not my own code (other than piecing it together). I wish I would still find the sources so I can quote them here but I can't find them anymore. Credits to the creators though! :-)

Next, open your CloudFront distribution and do the following:

1. Make sure your S3 bucket in the origin is configured as a REST endpoint and not a website endpoint, i.e. it must end on `.s3.amazonaws.com` and not have the word `website` in the hostname.
2. Also in the Origin settings, under "S3 bucket access", select "Yes use OAI (bucket can restrict access to only CloudFront)". In the setting below click on "Create OAI" to create a new OAI (unless you have an existing one and know what you're doing). And select "Yes, update the bucket policy" to allow AWS to add the necessary permissions to your OAI.
3. Finally, open your Behavior of the CloudFront distribution and scroll to the bottom. Under "Function associations", for "Viewer request" select "CloudFront Function" and select your newly created CloudFront function. Save your changes.

And that should be it. With a bit of luck a matter of a couple of minutes (realistically more, I know) and especially not additional complexity once this is all set up.